# Can not access object's properties inside my view model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have added the following two model view classes:

```
public class AssetCount
    {
        public int CustomerCount { get; set; }
        public int DataCenterCount { get; set; }
        public int FirewallCount { get; set; }
        public int RouterCount { get; set; }
        public int VirtualMachineCount { get; set; }
        public int ServerCount { get; set; }
        public int StorageDeviceCount { get; set; }
        public int RackCount { get; set; }
        public int SwitchCount { get; set; }
        public int CustomCount { get; set; }
    }


public class SystemInformation
    {

        public AssetCount AssetCount { get; set; }
        public ICollection<TechnologyAudit> TechnologyAudit { get; set; }
        public ICollection<AdminAudit> AdminAudit { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Technology> LatestTechnology { get; set; }
    }
```

But, inside my model class method, I was unable to access the AssetCount object's properties, such as:

```
public SystemInformation GetSystemInfo(int pagesize) 

        {
            SystemInformation s = new SystemInformation()
            {
                AssetCount.CustomerCount = entities.AccountDefinitions.Count() //I can not access the CustomerCount !!!!
```

So can anyone advise me what the problem is? Thanks.

Comment: Try changing the property name into something different than the class name. I presume that the compiler thinks that you're trying to access a static property. As Ufuk said, you need to initialize it.

Comment: Not just that, but the syntax of `AssetCount.CustomerCount` is invalid in such an initializer. You can set properties on the `SystemInformation` object, not do other things with those properties (like set their properties).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to initialize `AssetCount` property first:

```
SystemInformation s = new SystemInformation()
{
    AssetCount = new AssetCount { CustomerCount = entities.AccountDefinitions.Count() }
};
```